# Merging Cells in EXCEL VBA when ONLY cell reference numbers are available

Tags: excel, vba

I have used vba code like that below to merge 2 cells programmatically in EXCEL before:

Range("B2:B3").Merge

HOWEVER, instead of an absolute cell reference situation like that above, I now have a situation where I can only use a relative cell reference. For example, I have variable Row0 and Col0 that count the number of rows and columns from a particular reference cell. So, if I want to merge the reference cell (which may vary from application to application) with the one immediately to the right of it, I was hoping to use something like:

```
Cell1 = Cells(Row0, Col0).Address
Cell2 = Cells(Row0, Col0 + 1).Address

Range(Cell1:Cell2).Merge
```

However, this results in an error because apparently the quotes are expected, however, when adding the quotes, then the variables Cell1 and Cell2 are not resolved.

Range("Cell1:Cell2").Merge

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

In your example change

```
    Range(Cell1:Cell2).Merge
```

to

```
    Range(cell1 & ":" & cell2).Merge
```

As you have it you're trying to pass a string within the Range, but the `:` isn't surrounded by quotes.

Surround it with quotes and concatenate cell1 and cell2 with the `&` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the address at all:

```
Set Cell1 = Cells(Row0, Col0)
Set Cell2 = Cells(Row0, Col0 + 1)

Range(Cell1, Cell2).Merge
```

Or just:

```
Cells(Row0, Col0).Resize(1,2).Merge
```

Comment: Thank you both!! This is very helpful!!

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(Row0, Col0), Cells(Row0, Col0 + 1)).Merge

Comment: One followup question, though: I also have similar code for this statement:

Comment: Range(Cells(Row0, Col0)).Font.Bold = True

Comment: And I am getting a "Run time error 1004 - Method -Range of object'_Global' failed

Comment: `Cells(Row0, Col0).Font.Bold = True`  `Range()` takes either a string argument or two Range arguments.  `Cells(r, c)` already represents a Range object, so there's no need to wrap it in `Range()`